# Disable button with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am banging my head here with this and it seems so simple, but I can't seem to get this. The story goes I am working with NopCommerce which is an ASP.Net MVC application and what I am trying to do, is as the user is going through the checkout process and they are on the shipping page, I want the user to click the "continue" button but before the Shipping.Save method is called on the click event I want to open up a dialog box and pass it some information. Then on the dialog box, they choose yes/no and depending on what they choose as their selection it will either update their record if they choose yes and continue on as if the button was clicked originally or else if they click no then the box will close and again, the button would act like it was clicked originally to go to the next section.

So right now this is what the html looks like:

```
</li>
            <li id="opc-shipping" class="tab-section">
                <div class="step-title">
                    <span class="number">2</span>
                    <h2>Shipping address</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="checkout-step-shipping" class="step a-item" style="display: none;">
                    <form action="" id="co-shipping-form">
                    <div id="checkout-shipping-load">

                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Shipping.init('#co-shipping-form', 'http://localhost:15536/checkout/OpcSaveShipping/');
                        if ($("#shipping-address-select").length > 0) {
                            Shipping.newAddress(!$('#shipping-address-select').val());
                        }
                    </script>
                    <div class="buttons" id="shipping-buttons-container">
                        <p class="back-link">
                            <a href="#" onclick="Checkout.back(); return false;"><small>&laquo; </small>Back</a></p>
                        <input type="button" class="button-1 new-address-next-step-button" title="Continue" onclick="Shipping.save()" value="Continue" />
                        <span id="shipping-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display: none;"> Loading next step...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
```

I have tried many different thing but this is my last attempt:

```
 $('#shipping-buttons-container').on('click', function() {
    var me = $(this);
    me.offtmp('click'); //disable the click event temporaraly while performing ajax request
    //$.post(...).always(function() {
    //    me.ontmp('click'); //the ajax request is ready, now we can enable clicks again
    //});
});
```

Even just to try to get an alert to pop up this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: try using [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/): `me.off('click')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to "temporarily" disable the click event. You need to kill it or not. So, kill it. But, please keep in mind versions of IE prior to 9 don't handle that the same way as the regular browsers. At the top of your click function do this:

```
if (e.preventDefault) {
    // For modern browsers
    e.preventDefault();
}
else {
    // For older IE browsers
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Now you are free to display your message box/alert to get the user input. If they say "No"/"Cancel", just close the box. If they accept, then close the box and call a script to send the user to the next section. (It looks like you're not using a form, but that would be `$('#formID').submit();`.

Just be sure to not enter back into the click function again.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I will give these a try in the AM.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#shipping-buttons-container").click(function() {
  var me = $(this);
  me.unbind( "click");            
})
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I can still click the button.